# knockout - preselect data in multi select dropdown

Tags: knockout.js

I have a `IndustryData` observable array which will store data in the following format:

```
ID Name IsMapped 
1 Name1 0
2 Name2 1
3 Name3 0
4 Name4 1
```

I am using the below mentioned `select` to bind the data:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.IndustryData, selectedOptions: $root.IndustryDataSelectedValues, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

`IndustryDataSelectedValues` is an observable array which will store the selected values for the above `select` and it will be initially empty. My requirement is that the row which is having `IsMapped` value as 1 should be selected in my `multi select` control and those items should be available in `IndustryDataSelectedValues` observable array. In the above case `Name2` and `Name4` should be selected in my `multi select` control and these two items should be available in `IndustryDataSelectedValues` observable array.

How can I achieve this in knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this:

- you can have a writable computed which maps back and fort to your `IndustryDataSelectedValues`
- or if you only need to initiliaze your array once you can have a `initialize` method on your viewmodel what you call when the data is ready in the `IndustryData`

So you need something like that:

```
initialize: function () {
        this.IndustryDataSelectedValues(ko.utils.arrayMap(
        ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.IndustryData, function (item) {
            return item.IsMapped == 1
        }), function (item) {
            return item.id;
        }));
    }
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2t6Zp/).

Where with the `ko.utils.arrayFilter` you first select all the item where `IsMapped == 1` then with the `ko.utils.arrayMap` take the `id` property of the previously found items and store these ids in the `IndustryDataSelectedValues`